# i need a sql query to check reference of a column value available in 4 different tables, before deleting that column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table named as `Team_table` having a column `Team_Id` as a primary key, and 4 different table are `Team_Member`, `Team_Project`, `Team_Account`, `Team_link` also contains this `Team_Id`.

Before deleting a team from `Team_table`, I have to check its reference in all 4 tables. if this `Team_Id` found in any one table, user cant delete it.

I made following query but its not working-

```
select count(Team.Team_Id)
  from Team 
  join Team_Project on Team.Team_Id = Team_Project.Team_Id  
 right join Team_Member on Team.Team_Id = Team_member.Team_Id  
 right join Team_link on Team.Team_Id = Team_link.Team_Id  
 right join Team_Account on Team.Team_Id = Team_Account.Team_Id  
 where Team.Team_Id = 2
```

But its always giving me 0, while this team_Id is available in all tables.
Please suggest me right solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A group of `right join` ends up empty the last table is empty.  A group of `left join` ends up empty if the first table is empty.  But a group of `full join` will return any matching rows.  So consider replacing your `right join` with `full join`.

As another option, I find it clearer to use `not exists` clauses instead of `join` for this kind of query:

```
delete  t
from    Team t
where   t.Team_Id = @TeamId
        and not exists (select * from Team_Project where Team_Id = @TeamId)
        and not exists (select * from Team_Member where Team_Id = @TeamId)
        and not exists (select * from Team_link where Team_Id = @TeamId)
        and not exists (select * from Team_Account where Team_Id = @TeamId)
```

Per your comment, to retrieve the count:

```
select  count(*)
from    (
        select  Team_Id 
        from    Team_Project 
        union all
        select  Team_Id 
        from    Team_Member  
        union all
        select  Team_Id 
        from    Team_link    
        union all
        select  Team_Id 
        from    Team_Account 
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   Team_Id = @TeamId
```

Comment: andamor thanks for your reply, it worked.... but i need to do this by using join, and first i want to get count and than delete it by using a separate delete method.  you mentioned to use full join but it is not giving me right count, as it returned 150 in count, while it is available only 1 time in every table , can u give me right query by using join, to get count only.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
declare @teamid int=2;

Select Team_Id from Team_Project where Team_Id=@teamid union all
Select Team_Id from Team_Member  where Team_Id=@teamid union all
Select Team_Id from Team_link    where Team_Id=@teamid union all
Select Team_Id from Team_Account where Team_Id=@teamid; 

if @@ROW_COUNT=0 delete from TEAM where Team_Id=@teamid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(Team.Team_Id) 
from Team 
left join Team_Project 
   on Team.Team_Id=Team_Project.Team_Id  
left join Team_Member 
   on Team.Team_Id=Team_member.Team_Id  
left join Team_link 
   on Team.Team_Id=Team_link.Team_Id  
left join Team_Account 
   on Team.Team_Id= Team_Account.Team_Id  
where Team.Team_Id=2 and 
(Team_Project.Team_Id is not null
 of 
 Team_member.Team_Id is not null
 or 
 Team_link.Team_Id is not null
 or
 Team_Account.Team_Id is not null)
```

Comment: This wouldn't return any rows if `Team` doesn't have a row for that team.  That might be OK since in that case there's nothing to delete.